# Seleccionar multiples filas mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito 3 filas de una tabla que tienen determinados id.

Esta es mi consulta actual que obtiene solo un registro

```
$query='SELECT precios.id_precio, precios.precio, precios.descarga, precios.carga FROM wifmaxco_web.precios WHERE precios.id_precio="1"';  

$tabla=mysql_query($query);
```

Pero necesito hacer una consulta de varios registros basado en los id 1, 8, 14, 20.

Hay manera de recuperar varias filas con una sola consulta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar la función "**IN**"

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT precios.id_precio, precios.precio, precios.descarga, precios.carga
   FROM wifmaxco_web.precios
   WHERE precios.id_precio IN (1,8,14,20)';
?>
```

Luego deberias iterar el resultado:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

**Nota:** Deberias usar **mysqli** ya que **mysql** esta deprecado.
Mas info aca: http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría usando 'IN'. Es la forma más corta de hacerlo. Aquí tienes ejemplos y demás explicaciones.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no nos explicas el uso de `in`? Así si el link cae algún día, podemos seguir teniendo información válida al respecto.

Comment: IN lleva como parámetro una lista de valores. Cuando tú consulta (en este caso el ID) coincida con cualquiera de ellos, devolverá esa fila. También tienes el operador NOT IT que hace lo opuesto. Es decir, ignora aquellas filas cuyos valores están en la lista y selecciona todas las demás.

Comment: He puesto NOT IT pero es NOT IN, no me deja corregir la App del móvil

Comment: Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/27081/edit) la respuesta e incluye la información que escribiste en el comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, tu consulta quedaría así, lo puedes hacer con sql:

```
        $query='SELECT precios.id_precio, precios.precio, precios.descarga, precios.carga 
    FROM wifmaxco_web.precios 
WHERE precios.id_precio="1" or precios.id_precio="24" or precios.id_precio="45645"';
```

Comment: creo que deberías usar "OR" en vez de "||"

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar **precios.id_precio="1"** por **precios.id_precio IN (1,2,3)**

En tu ejemplo quedaría así

```
SELECT precios.id_precio, precios.precio, precios.descarga, precios.carga FROM wifmaxco_web.precios WHERE precios.id_precio IN (1,2,3)
```

Lo que hace el operador IN en este caso es filtrar por cada uno de los elementos que van entre paréntesis.

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene varias vías. La primera es usar "OR", engorroso pero funciona;

```
$query='SELECT precios.id_precio, precios.precio, precios.descarga, precios.carga
FROM wifmaxco_web.precios
WHERE precios.id_precio="1"
    OR precios.id_precio="8"
    OR precios.id_precio="14"
    OR precios.id_precio="20"';
```

Puedes usar IN como en otras respuestas;

```
$query='SELECT precios.id_precio, precios.precio, precios.descarga, precios.carga
FROM wifmaxco_web.precios
WHERE precios.id_precio IN("1", "8", "14", "20")';
```

El "IN" puede combinarse con subqueries es decir otro SELECT. Hay mas información de eso en la página de mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un `in`

```
$query = 'select precios.id_precio, precios.precio, precios.descarga, precios.carga
   from wifmaxco_web.precios
   where precios.id_precio IN (1,8,14,20)';

$Resultado = mysqli_query($conexionBD,$query)
or die(mysqli_error($conexionBD));/// en esta parte si se presenta algun error la pagina te lo mostrara

//// luego recorres cada una de las filas con un array asociativo para recuperar los datos por su encabezado.

while($ResultadoArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Resultado)){

$Array = $ResultadoArray;

$PRECIO = $Array['ENCABEZADO DE LA COLUMNA'];

echo $PRECIO;//// y aqui ves el valor que va retornando a la hora de recorrer el ciclo.

}

while($ResultadoArray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Resultado)){

$Array[] = $ResultadoArray; /// esto si bien quieres luego imprimir un json

}

$Json = json_encode($Array);
echo $Json;
```

Espero y te sirva, saludos.